# Is my subpanel service entrance cable secured properly?

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel

This will be a 100a sub panel. Using Al 1-1-1-3 SER.

[image: New Subpanel]

Questions:
1.) Is this SER feeder wired and secured sufficiently?

2.) How about here where it enters the main panel? Can I put some form of insulation in this conduit to seal it? (Note there is a new wall frames in front of this original foundation wall so this will all be protected behind drywall.)

[image: Where new Sub feeder enters main panel]

New load center sticker:
[image: Load center sticker]

Comment: 1 - Why would you loop them? Makes sense on small stuff sometimes so you have extra length to rearrange things, but not on the big feeder wires.
3 - That looks totally *wrong*. Should be 1 or 2 (or maybe 3) cables *per knockout* into the box, and each knockout gets a clamp. Number of cables per knockout determined by available space but primarily by the clamp's specifications.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the subpanel's label please?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact on the looping, thanks...just wanted to make sure. That second photo is the main panel, as the original builder did it. But I don't think you'd have individual clamps for each circuit (or even 2) on an exterior subpanel like what I've seen on interior panels where the circuits conductors are going out through the top.

Comment: The looping is nice for a) thermal expansion and b) if you ever change the panel and the next one's taller.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel hi, I added the photo of the load center sticker as requested.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica thanks. Added bends and left extra slack in ceiling above.

Comment: Not sure how much of a concern thermal expansion is, but having a bit of a service loop or flexibility is always handy.